# Remove numeric key from mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, unset, php-mongodb

I am having the below document in the collection for example.
I want to remove data with numeric keys from the document. for example "0" in the below document.

I have tried the below code

```php
$manager = Core_BP_BaseTableMongo::connection();
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->update($wh, ['$unset' => array("0" => true)]);
$result = $manager->executeBulkWrite(Core_BP_BaseTableMongo::getDatabaseName().'.'.$collection_name, $bulk);
```

Document

```json
{
    "0": {
        "datetimestamp_id": "1613044151UyZKNjrs7l",
        "product_id": ObjectId("5fe155e4045a855ae211e2a4"),
        "image": "",
        "squence": 0,
        "slug": "ks1215",
        "name": "KS1215",
        "dimensions": "",
        "brand_id": ObjectId("5fe12bbbab6506780bd925a3"),
        "brand": "Scihome",
        "brand_slug": "scihome",
        "country": "China",
        "description": "<p>The backrest has a front and rear pushable design that opens to give a bed. The middle of the armrest and the feet are made of stainless steel for a modern look. The two color combinations are more compatible with the style of different living rooms. The activity is on the head to satisfy more sitting and crowd use.</p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Dimensions :</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>3 left: L - 1860 mm x W - 1130/1370 mm x H - 835&nbsp;mm</li>\r\n\t<li>1 no : L - 770 mm x W - 1130/1370 mm x H - 835&nbsp;mm</li>\r\n\t<li>lying right : L - 1090 mm x W - 1800/2040 mm x H - 835&nbsp;mm</li>\r\n\t<li>footstool : L - 1080 mm x W - 770 mm x H - 410&nbsp;mm</li>\r\n\t<li>coffee table : L - 350 mm x W - 1070 mm x H - 645 mm</li>\r\n</ul>",
        "qty": 1,
        "uom": "Each",
        "area": "Drawing hall",
        "notes": "No leather"
    },
    "_id": ObjectId("602519b69613e33c1576866d"),
    "title": "XYZ",
    "project_type": "Duplex Apartments",
    "customer": {
        "customer_id": ObjectId("5fe31123045a855ae22a29e8"),
        "name": "Jay",
        "email": "bd02@xyz.com"
    },
    "status": "Pending",
    "request_date": "2021-02-11 17:19:10",
    "rfq": false,
    "products": [
        {
            "datetimestamp_id": "1613044151UyZKNjrs7l",
            "product_id": ObjectId("5fe155e4045a855ae211e2a4"),
            "image": "",
            "squence": 0,
            "slug": "ks1215",
            "name": "KS1215",
            "dimensions": "",
            "brand_id": ObjectId("5fe12bbbab6506780bd925a3"),
            "brand": "Scihome",
            "brand_slug": "scihome",
            "country": "China",
            "description": "<p>The backrest has a front and rear pushable design that opens to give a bed. The middle of the armrest and the feet are made of stainless steel for a modern look. The two color combinations are more compatible with the style of different living rooms. The activity is on the head to satisfy more sitting and crowd use.</p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Dimensions :</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>3 left: L - 1860 mm x W - 1130/1370 mm x H - 835&nbsp;mm</li>\r\n\t<li>1 no : L - 770 mm x W - 1130/1370 mm x H - 835&nbsp;mm</li>\r\n\t<li>lying right : L - 1090 mm x W - 1800/2040 mm x H - 835&nbsp;mm</li>\r\n\t<li>footstool : L - 1080 mm x W - 770 mm x H - 410&nbsp;mm</li>\r\n\t<li>coffee table : L - 350 mm x W - 1070 mm x H - 645 mm</li>\r\n</ul>",
            "qty": 1,
            "uom": "Each",
            "area": "Drawing hall",
            "notes": "No leather"
        }
    ],
    "shared": [
        {
            "customer_id": ObjectId("5fe31123045a855ae22a29e8"),
            "name": "Jay",
            "email": "bd02@xyz.com",
            "permission": "Owner"
        }
    ],
    "audit_created_by": "Jay",
    "audit_created_date": {
        "sec": 1613044150
    },
    "audit_ip": "172.18.0.1",
    "audit_updated_by": null,
    "audit_updated_date": {
        "sec": 1618221803
    },
    "is_deleted": false
}
```

I tried $unset as well but it gives me an error *Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead. For example: {$mod: {: ...}} not {$unset: [ true ]}*

Comment: You can remove a field (or key) which is a number using `$unset`. Please post the code you had tried.

Comment: @prasad_ added query code into the question.

Comment: You just unset the field `"0"`. For example, `db.collection.update( { // your_filter }, { $unset: { '0': '' }})`.

Comment: I think the syntax `array("0" => true)` is not correct. See examples at [MongoDB PHP Driver Update](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#update-documents).

Comment: thanks, figureout
converted array to object and worked

Comment: worked this one, $bulk->update($wh, ['$unset' => (object)array("0" => true)]);